# How to prevent Mathematica from creating gigantic wl-stream-stdout-* files?

Tags: performance-tuning, configuration, processlink

I have been running a *Mathematica* computation for the last few hours.

I just discovered that a file with a name of the form

```
~/.Mathematica/ApplicationData/ProcessLink/Streams/wl-stream-stdout-<nonce-id>
```

...is growing rapidly (it's already ~70G).

**Q:**  Is there a way to configure *Mathematica* so that it does not generate these gigantic files?

---

Clearly, my *Mathematica* session is responsible for writing to this file, but it's not clear to me what in my computation warrants it.

The computation I'm running is entirely local, and it is not supposed to perform any disk IO until the very end of the computation, which should not happen in the next 10-15 hours.

In a bit more detail: the computation entails the following sequence:

1. reading a large (~6G) numeric matrix from disk (once);
2. analyzing the data and generate several plots; this should take ~20 hours, and involves *no explicit disk IO*;
3. exporting two files (one png and one svg) after the computation is completed.

I don't understand how `ProcessLink` got into this picture...

Comment: @Shadowray: the matrix is saved as an *.mx file, and I read it in using `Import`.

Comment: Could you check what is inside this large file? If you have Linux or OSX you can use terminal to run `head -n10 pathToHugeFile` to print first 10 lines of the `pathToHugeFile`

Comment: My guess is that some of your data analysing routines (maybe some custom packages) are using an external program via `ProcessLink` and `ProcessLink` uses files to store communication between MMA and external program. When a lot of data beeing transmited, the files become huge. The first step is to find which function is using `ProcessLink`.

Comment: @Shadowray: Thanks for your suggestions.  I had to delete the file, since it was approaching 100G.  The process is still running, though.  I'll troubleshoot the problem further once the process finishes.  (I don't want to risk it dying for lack of memory.)